# F#: Saving JSON data

Tags: json, f#

I am new to programming and F# is my first language.

Here are the relevant parts of my code:

```
let internal saveJsonToFile<'t> (someObject:'t) (filePath: string) =  
    use fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate) 
    (new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof<'t>)).WriteObject(fileStream, someObject)

let testList = new List<Fighter>()

saveJsonToFile testList<Fighter> @"G:\User\Fighters.json"
```

I have previously created an F# record of type Fighter.

When I try to run "saveJsonToFile testList @"G:\User\Fighters.json"", "testList" is underscored in red with the error message: "Unexpected type arguments".

What went wrong? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your `testList` is a *value*, not a function.
Second, it doesn't have a generic argument, everything in its body is concrete.

If you want it to be a function, give it a parameter.
If you want it to be generic, say so in the body.

`let testList () = new List<'a>()`
`saveJsonToFile testList<Fighter>() @"G:\User\Fighters.json"`

And finally, the `List` you're trying to create probably resolves to F#'s own `List`, which is a module, not a type.
If you meant to create the .NET's `System.Collections.Generic.List`, then you need to specify the full type name:

`let testList () = new System.Collections.Generic.List<'a>()`

But if you meant to create an F# native list, use one of its constructors:

`let testList () = []`

Comment: Instead of `new System.Collections.Generic.List<'a>()`, you can use `new ResizeArray<'a>()`.  Also, `[]` isn't a constructor; it's a value.  Try this: `System.Object.ReferenceEquals([],[])`

Comment: I do not understand your point.  Of course the instances will not be the same if they are of different type.

Comment: My point was that it is incorrect to use VM-level concept, such as reference comparison, to support arguments about language-level terminology. ADT cases are commonly called "value constructors" (or "data constructors") even if they don't have parameters and regardless of lower-level implementation.

Comment: Point taken, but in the case of `[]`, the spec says "The pattern [] is a union case pattern that matches the “nil” union case of F# list values."  The term "value constructor" does not appear.  The term "data constructor" appears once, without being defined.  In the grammar section, `[]` is defined under "operators."

Comment: ADTs are a general concept, not limited top F#.